# How can we use constraint in every individual element in an array in cplex?

Tags: constraints, cplex, forall

Why is my forall loop not working to apply an constraint to all the individual values stored in my variable. For eg: if there are 100 values stored under a variable k, how  can I apply the constraint where each value is less than a certain constant.

Answer (score -1):

```
 range r=1..100;
 
 int value[i in r]=2*i;
 
 dvar int k[r];
 
 maximize sum(i in r) k[i];
 subject to
 {
   forall(i in r) k[i]<=value[i];
 }
 
 assert forall(i in r) k[i]==2*i;
```

works fine